# Ruby on rails making an app for smartphone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to build an app that use in the backend Ruby on Rails. However my problem comes in the lack of information i found on it. My goals is not just to create a website but an application that interacts with it, like my android facebook app when pressing menu I get button like logout and so on.

I am wondering if their exists tutorial on how to build an application but using rails or should i scrap my entire website and do it in php. I am looking for guide and tutorial. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build an app on any platform and make it interact with your Rails-based server using HTTP requests (like AJAX).
You can send information back and forth using JSON or XML; you would probably need to make a new set of actions for the app to use.

There is no reason to use PHP.  *ever*.

Comment: To understand rails allow me to generate xml/json and then from that i can choose a software like phonegab or rhomobile and then create a seta of action. How can i define those actions?

Answer (score 3):

A little unclear from your original question, but if you are looking to create a mobile app using Ruby (and a structure similar to Ruby on Rails) then you may be interested in [Rhomobile](http://www.motorola.com/Business/US-EN/Business+Product+and+Services/Software+and+Applications/RhoMobile+Suite). It is a cross-platform mobile application framework that uses Ruby for its backend code, and follows a structure similar to (older) Ruby on Rails versions.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your problem, you want to use the robustness of `Ruby` to develop a native app (not just another app that mirrors a website).

The best thing I know of for this is `RubyMotion`. The bummer is the cost (`$200`). But then you would get to accomplish your task.